# Preventing setState rerenders entire functional component

Tags: reactjs

In a class component when the state or props was changed the render method will execute, but I don't know in a functional component when the same happens which part of the code is rerendered?

Comment: The entire function reruns.

Comment: @NicholasTower How to prevent rerender a local variable, I don't want to create a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you have some expensive calculation inside your component that you want to skip, you can use the [useMemo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). It will do the calculation the first time, and then on subesequent times it will only recalculate if one of the dependencies change. For example:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

const Example = ({ people }) => {
  const [ageFilter, ageFilter] = useState(10);
  const filteredPeople = useMemo({
    return people.filter(person => person.age >= ageFilter);
  }, [people, ageFilter]);

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredList.map(person=> (
        // some components
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can use `React.memo`. Similarly for class component React provides [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

It is mentioned in [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

> If your function component renders the same result given the same
>   props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost
>   in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
>   rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

So, you need to use `React.memo`.