# ..Use state error: Too many re-renders React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Well, I'm trying to get products from my API and display them in my 'Products' component. Everything looks fine and I can reach every single product on my browser if I just don't try to increment `count` but the problem is when I try to increment `count` by using `setCount` in my JSX I get this following error `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

I just want to increment the`count` by one when I loop through `Products`. For example, If I got 3 `products` I want my `count` to be 1,2 then 3.

This following code is my `products`component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getProductKinds, getProducts } from "../lookup";

function Products() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const myCallBack = (response, status) => {
      if (status === 200) {
        console.log("products resnpose:", response);
        setProducts(response);
      }
    };
    getProducts(myCallBack);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => {
        console.log(count);
        setCount(count + 1);
        if (count === 0) {
          return (
            <div className="card-group container">
              <div className="card shadow" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                <img
                  className="card-img-top"
                  src="https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/65708b701baa3a84883ad48301624b44/2de058af"
                  alt="Card image cap"
                />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <p className="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                    up the bulk of the card's content.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: Why do you use a state variable for the `count`? `setCount` in the return statement causes the rendering loop. What are you trying to achieve by the `count` state variable exactly? If you want to render only for the first `product` item, you can use the index as a second argument in the `map` function.

Comment: Actually nothing much. I just want to increment  ```count``` when i pass every single ```product``` in ```map```.

Comment: you shouldn't do ```setCount(count + 1);``` in the JSX, do it in the ```useEffect```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference ? i mean why ```useState``` went to a infinite loop when i tried to use it in JSX ?

Comment: @AliZiyaÇEVİK Then what? Maybe you can provide more information about what you need the count variable for? Are you planning on using it later?

Comment: I just encountered with this error randomly and just wanted to know why am i getting this error. I have  no plans on using it later.

Comment: 1st render -> map through products from the 1st item -> setCount causes re-render -> map through products from the 1st item -> setCount causes re-render ... You programs won't continue the map from where it stopped the last time, but it starts it over. `useState` should be used conditionally upon clicks for example or in `useEffect`.

Comment: @BlackMath I think when there are no products he wants to return an empty component (a component which indicates that there is nothing to show), otherwise, he increments the count by one.

Answer (score 1):

`setCount(count + 1);` is called inside the map function and every time your component goes into that map function this is called, updating the state, resulting in an infinite loop.

You can increment count inside useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCount(count+1);
    const myCallBack = (response, status) => {
      if (status === 200) {
        console.log("products resnpose:", response);
        setProducts(response);
      }
    };
    getProducts(myCallBack);
  });
```

Comment: ```count``` value didn't increase when I passed through every single ```product ```. I just kept got the same ```count``` value. I want to increase the ```count``` value when i go through every single ```product``` with ```map```.

Comment: if you want to increment count in each iteration of map, and don't want the component to re-render you can use React.memo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139618/preventing-setstate-rerenders-entire-functional-component

Comment: Yeah got it now, you can either use React.memo and read about how to use it (it only enables re-rendering for certain state variables) or you can just use products.map((product, index) and index+1 will be your count automatically

Comment: Using Index might be good for this situation but I think I'm just gonna create a variable and increment that variable when i loop ```products```.

Comment: Yep, whatever works. Learning memoization for React can come in handy for later though. Happy coding